# Use array_push() inside a foeach loop.

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php

$files = array();

function listFolderFiles($dir, &$files){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            else array_push($files, array('file' => $dir.'/'.$ff, 'hash' => hash_file('md5', $dir.'/'.$ff)));
        }

    }
}
listFolderFiles('/var/www', $files);
var_dump($files);

?>
```

`$dir.'/'.$ff` return all the information i want.but when i use array push it return only 9 element of array.how can i solve this issue ? what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing the `$files` array through recursively:

```
if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff, $files);
                                  ^^^^^^
} ...
```